# C# change system date time format

Tags: c#

I am looking for a way to change my system's date time format from 12 hour to 24 hour. Suppose, currently, I have the system time in 12 or 24 hour format and I want to change it to 24 hour format programatically. How is it possible ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need a batch file solution, or a C# solution?

Comment: I am looking for a c# solution, since my actual program is in C#.

Comment: you need PInvoke to access windows settings.

Comment: Then you'll have to PInvoke the function of the Windows API provided in the answer below. If you don't know how to PInvoke check out one of the gazillion tutorials on how to do that: [Google: PInvoke Tutorial](https://www.google.de/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=PInvoke+tutorial&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=AL-bVbXvB6qF8Qfkj4HYCw)

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Do you really want to change that for the system or actually just for your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SetLocaleInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API function with [`LOCALE_ITIME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373808%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) constant passed as `LCType` parameter.

**EDIT:**

Here is an example of setting 12-hour time format.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace DllImportTest
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private const string TimeFormat12Hour = "0";
        private const string TimeFormat24Hour = "1";

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var ok = WindowsApi.SetLocaleInfo(0, WindowsApi.LOCALE_ITIME, TimeFormat12Hour);
            if (!ok)
                throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Windows API call error {0}.", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
        }
    }

    internal static class WindowsApi
    {
        public const int LOCALE_ITIME = 0x00000023;

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern bool SetLocaleInfo(uint locale, uint lcType, string lcData);
    }
}
```

Please note, that [`SetLocalInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation states it is necessary to broadcast `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message to all top-level windows after making an international change to system parameters. Doing this will require using of another Windows API function [`SendMessageTimeout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This part is omitted in the example.

Comment: Added a simple example.